# How to export PSD file to SVG in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, svg

I have a PSD file. I want to convert the PSD to SVG file using Photoshop CS6. Anyone able to tell me how to do this?

Comment: brother your question is already asked .. check this out   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175499/how-to-convert-psd-into-svg-image-while-preserving-layers

Comment: that question was marked as off topic.  Presumably it is a question for graphicdesign not stackoverflow.  If that question is closed, is it not counterproductive to close this question as a duplicate?

Comment: In photoshop 7: (file > export > Paths to Illustrator) and (in illustrator export to svg)

Answer (score 2):

As I know PS don't have ability to save to SVG. You will need separate vector editor for this. Anyway, can you share a screenshot what you have in mind?

Comment: Hi, 

do you know any vector editor for this ?

Comment: I personally use Adobe Illustrator. If you want can save SVG for you.